# Is there a way to fix broken mouse that double clicks and mouse wheel not responding and right clicks when mouse wheel used?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, scrolling

I have tried the screwdriver to fix the mouse. and it is USB mouse issues which double click, the mouse wheel is not responding and it is to right-click repeatedly when the mouse wheel is used for a long time. Is there a way to fix it?

Operating System

Windows 7 Professional 32-bit SP1

CPU:

AMD Athlon II X2 250

Regor 45nm Technology

RAM:

2.00GB Dual-Channel DDR2 @ 332MHz (5-5-5-15)

Motherboard:

Acer RS780DV (AM2)

Graphics:

E55-2 (1280x960@60Hz)

895MB ATI Radeon HD 3200 Graphics (Acer Incorporated [ALI])

Storage:

149GB Seagate ST3160318AS ATA Device (SATA)

Optical Drives:

ATAPI DVD A DH16AASH ATA Device

Audio:

Realtek High Definition Audio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to be a mechanical failure of the mouse so I'd suggest to replace it. Try a spare mouse to be really sure. There are so many types of mice its hard to suggest how to physically fix it. If its an expensive or well-known brand you MAY have hope that someone else took apart to fix, but it's unlikely.